# Windows 7 home premium(64) hardware limitations

Tags: windows-7, windows, performance, hardware-rec, 3d-graphics

I'm one click away of buying **Intel I7 Ivy Bridge 3770 3.4Ghz Gaming Pc Computer 1tb 16Gb GTX 550 Ti 1Gb Z11+** the computer is without Windows but I have extra copy of Windows 7 Home Premium 64bit.

The thing is that I discovered there is limitation around physical memory on Home Premium 64 (it allows up to 16GB RAM , Windows 7 Professional 64 and above up to 192GB). Ram of this computer is 16GB (Vengeance 1600MHZ DDR3) so I hope that it wont be a problem. (please response if you know about any other limitation around RAM I'm not aware of)

**The thing I want to ask:** If there is some other limitation on other hardware for this computer with Windows 7 Home Premium that I'm not aware of

...and is there any other reason for me to buy Windows 7 Profesional (or Ultimate) from hardware  performance perspective? The computer will be used only for 3D modelling and rendering, no LAN work or super security

(I can upgrade W7 any time or buy it later, it's just I can have few pounds discount now, but if there's no reason I wont)

reference links: [Windows 7 RAM says only 16 GB of 24 GB of RAM is available](https://superuser.com/questions/405277/windows-7-ram-says-only-16-gb-of-24-gb-of-ram-is-available)  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions#Comparison_chart

thank you

Comment: Sounds like you already found [the answer to your question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions#Comparison_chart). Yes, there are RAM limitations, but as you've already discovered, 16 GB is within range for Home Premium.

Comment: As the previous comment suggests, RAM is the only hardware limitation. The other features that are present in professional and ultimate are aimed more at added security and business use..

Comment: So no other effect around that RAM is Vengeance or 1600MHZ ? (sorry for this dumb question but I'm now paranoid, it was shock for me to discover even the 16GB RAM stuff :) )

Comment: I actually have the same RAM in my machine.. it might require manually setting to 1600mhz in the bios but apart from that.. no, no problems.. its a solid piece of kit.

Comment: @equivalent8: The only real limit is the *capacity* of the RAM (the 16GB). The *speed* or *throughput* is not limited by Windows. This is also true for other components (not just RAM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the amount of RAM is not an issue for you, then it's OK. FYI there's no Vengance RAM, it's Corsair. Corsair is one of the high-end producers of RAM, and it shouldn't be any problem with those memories.

There are no other hardware limitations that I know of.

The only limitations are software features. The main features that I would miss are Domain Join and Remote Desktop Connection. If you won't miss them, then you can stay with Home Premium.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Professional and Ultimate is way better then Windows Home. All the user management is way better and it comes also with the Windows XP mode. Personally I don't think Windows Home is good for a work computer. Nice-to-have is also the localization feature.

Comment: If I agree, it's just I have unused Home Premium at home and don't wan't to invest extra money if there's no reason from hardware performance perspective. The computer will be used only for latest 3D modelling software, no need for XP mode by only one person

Comment: @equivalent8: You can sell your copy at e-bay?

Comment: :) good thought and thanx for that, but lets keep the discussion around how (or whether) Windows 7 Home Premium differ in hardware performance from Windows 7 Professional/Ultimate

Comment: @equivalent8: There is none. Except for the Windows XP mode. Some older programm needs thats. That can be a hardware thing, too? BTW. not anybody can buy such an expensive box??? You don't need a Windows Home.